# Cyclic dependencies between sources of a package

Tags: go, compiler-errors, compilation, package

Let's say you have a package `mypack` with two source files `mypack/a.go` and `mypack/b.go`. Both of those source files depend on each another but the Go compiler doesn't complain. If you split that package into two, `apack/a.go` and `bpack/b.go`, the Go compiler will say `import cycle not allowed`.

My understanding of how package dependencies are handled is that the compiler will construct a graph of the imports. The graph is analyzed and somehow (I would love to learn about the algorithm that does this!) the order of compilation calculated. The order cannot be calculated if there is a cycle in the graph so the compiler complains.

What I don't understand is how the Go compiler is able to resolve dependencies between sources of a package but not able to resolve dependencies between packages. If the two sources depend on each other then you have to do some crazy acrobatics and compile them both at the same time somehow.

Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: A package is compiled as a single unit, regardless of how many source files are used. This shouldn't really be that mysterious.

Comment: Further, your assertion that "The order cannot be calculated if there is a cycle" is simply wrong. It's trivial to calculate such things--many languages do this. Go prohibits this, though, as a matter of policy, not because it's impossible.

Comment: @Flimzy Your comments are worth a real response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] how the Go compiler is able to resolve dependencies between sources of a package but not able to resolve dependencies between packages. If the two sources depend on each other then you have to do some crazy acrobatics and compile them both at the same time somehow.

The question is based on *wrong* assumptions on how Go code is structured and compiled: A source file **does** **not** have a dependency by definition.  A package has dependencies (all imports from all its source files). Dependencies are packages (not source files). To compile a package all dependencies have to be available *before* compilation starts.

You really must stop thinking in terms of source files. Source files have (almost) no meaning in how Go code is compiled. A package's source may consist of one or several source files and this is basically the *only* point where source files enter compiling Go code. Everything relevant revolves around packages and packages only: You compile packages, you import packages, etc.

(Just for completeness: Build tags work on source level and package initialization can depend on source code organization and by manual invoking gc you can do more than through the go tool.)

Answer (score 1):

A package is compiled as a single unit, regardless of how many source files are used. This shouldn't really be that mysterious.

Further, your assertion that "The order cannot be calculated if there is a cycle" is simply wrong. It's trivial to calculate such things--many languages do this. Go prohibits this, though, as a matter of policy, because it leads to tight coupling of code, and code that is difficult to understand, not because it's impossible.

Comment: You haven’t really answered my question. The Go compiler cannot simply concatenate the two source files and compile them as one big unit because there is a cyclic dependency. The compiler cannot put one file in front of the other.

Comment: Despite this, the compiler is still able to figure it out. That is my question